# How to read all comments from notepad++ file and paste it to another files with steps using MACROS

Tags: macros, notepad++

I have 18 text files in a directory. I want to read comments from each of 18 files and copy paste those comments in new file with suitable names.

I know we can do this using Macros by following below steps
1. Search for lines starting with "#" till EOF in single file
2. Copy them to a new file.
3. repeat for another one.

Need this

But I am not sure how to do this using MACROS in notepadd++, and I dont want to do it manually.
If anyone can guide on this, would be helpful.

Comment: Why using Npp and not write a script?

Answer (score 0):

How about using `Find in Files` by `^(#.*)$` in a directory with filter `*.py*`, then copy it to new files by hand. If you want a 100% automatic process, you should write a python tool, Notepad++ can't do all the functions you need.

[image]

Comment: yeah same I can do it manually in notepad++, i was looking if its possible to automate, Appreciate your reply. Thank you.